# Как использовать кортежи в конструкторе структуры

Tags: c#, struct

Имеется конструктор структуры

```
 public DataStruct(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            this.dateTime = dateTime; //Поле
            this.Title = string.Empty; //Автосвойство
            this.Discription = string.Empty; //Автосвойство
            this.IndexLine = 0; //Автосвойство

        }
```

У меня задача заменить все строки тела конструктора на кортеж типа (n...)=(n1...).
Отсюда вопрос, как это сделать?
Я пробовал this.(T1,T2...Tn) = (значение1, значение2...значение n), но VS выдает ошибку, объясните где я ошибся и как это работает?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `где я ошибся` - `this` должен быть у значений, которые имеют одинаковые названия с параметрами свойств, а не к кортежу целиком. То есть, в вашем случае будет `public DataStruct(DateTime dateTime) => (this.dateTime, Title, Discription, IndexLine) = (dateTime, string.Empty, string.Empty, 0);`, можете, конечно, прописать везде `this.`, но зачем? Также у вас немного странный конструктор, ибо зачем заполнять пустотой строки? Да и int значение по умолчанию 0, а исходя из этого, весь ваш код сводится к простому `public DataStruct(DateTime dateTime) => this.dateTime = dateTime;`.

Comment: Какая версия .NET? Покажите структуру целиком и ту строчку, которую вы хотите написать, но она не компилируется